# Cassandra permanent ReadTimeoutException

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

**Environment**

I have a following environment:

- Cassandra 2.1.0
- 5 nodes in one DC, 4 nodes in second DC
- 2500 writes per seconds
- minimal reads (usually none, sometimes few)

**Problem**

After a few weeks of running I cannot read any data from my cluster, because I have `ReadTimeoutException` like following:

```
ERROR [Thrift:15] 2015-01-07 14:16:21,124 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:219 - Error occurred during processing of message.
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 2 responses.
```

To be precise it is not only problem in my cluster, The second one was described here: [Cassandra GC takes 30 seconds and hangs node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843538/cassandra-gc-takes-30-seconds-and-hangs-node) and I will try to use fix from [CASSANDRA-6541](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6541) as leshkin suggested

**Question**

I know that I probably provide not enough information but I don't have an idea for what I should look for. I know that I can query ONE instead of QUORUM, but only QUORUM  option provides me reliable data.

Comment: Use "TRACING ON" before running your query via 'cqlsh' (CQL interactive terminal) to see what's Cassandra busy doing. http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html

Comment: @omid I do not run my command in CQLSH, but using cassandra driver, and as I know in CQLSH commands doesn't use QUORUM but ONE

Comment: @Garath you set the consistency in cqlsh using the CONSISTENCY command.  It defaults to ONE.

Comment: @Zanson you are right. I found this option some time ago